# Test for difference in distributions with different sample size

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance

Not sure whether the question fits here. During the validation of a model, by inspecting the estimated scores on a holdout sample (~500 data points), we can roughly get an image of what will the out-of-sample distribution look like. The data generating process of the distributions is a scoring model, so it will not be a continuous distribution even in theory.

After launching the model live and collecting new data points (~50 cases), the observed score distribution seems significantly different. However, the model vendor claims that the sample is too small to even start the discussion.

Now, we keep collecting more points, but the distribution does not seem to converge to the expected one.

**My question:**
What could be a good tool/test to estimate how significant are the differences of the distributions?

One idea is to just simply bootstrap the "holdout" sample and randomly pick subsets of size $50$ with replacement, to gauge the probability that our new collected data points are from the same distribution.

Could classical tests i.e. Kolmogorov-Smirnov would work here? In our case, there are many values from the tails of the expected distribution, which, if I'm not wrong, should weaken the K-S with small samples.

What would be the optimal size of the subsample, such, that we could in confidence claim that the observed differences in distribution is significant?

Edit:

Observed (in red) vs expected from the holdout (black) ECDF.

[image: Observed (in red) vs expected from the holdout (black) ECDF.]

Comment: I would use the K-S test as you suggested. This will tell you if the disturbing are significantly different from one another.

Comment: @CFD I'm cautious of K-S though yet, since with lack of tail values (from the smaller end), the distribution seems to be shifted to the right, and K-S is obviously showing high significance. I'm not sure though, whether by collecting a larger sample, some smaller values might shift the distribution back. In other words, I'm not sure how to counter the small sample effects.

Comment: @CFD I've included the ecdf's of the distributions [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuMJh3zFfO3liMli7h_9mT8jYmJpWg?e=c0cxXw). While the distribution seems shifted, is a correction possible with a larger sample?

Comment: thanks! To me it looks like 2 different distributions and I'd doubt that more sampling will make them converge

Comment: For sample sizes, "small" means tests do not have sufficient power to detect the inherent differences.  In that sense, this is a *huge* sample because it is blatantly obvious the distributions differ.  Perhaps your conversations should refocus on *how* they differ and by *how much*.

Comment: CFD, @whuber, thank you both for the input. By playing around with the data, it looks like around 100-200 random data points from the "expected" distribution would shift the distribution back, which seems a bit too large for it to be an outlier.

Comment: @whuber, is it possible to use moments comparison to measure how much they are differ?

Comment: @Nick That's possible.  It tends to lead to poor procedures because moments become exquisitely sensitive to extreme data as the order of the moment increases.

Comment: @whuber, may be usage quantiles will be more stable.